# Firebase saving data with custom key results in setValue is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When saving to firebase I am trying to set a custom key rather than using the one generated by firebase in a regular push.  It seemed pretty straight forward as this is the way I've seen other people doing it.  Can anyone see anything wrong with what I am doing?

```
export const startAddMovie = (movieData = {}) => {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const uid = getState().auth.uid; 
      const {
        title = '',
        ratingComment = '',
        rating = '',
        createdAt = 0,
      } = movieData;
      const movie = { title, ratingComment, rating, createdAt };
  
     // the next line works perfectly but it sets the ID of the new entry for me
     database.ref(`users/${uid}/movies`).push(movie);

    // the next line fails with error _firebase2.default.ref(...).child(...).setValue is not a function
      database.ref(`users/${uid}/movies`).child('1234').setValue(movie);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to set a node in the realtime database in the documentation. This is one possible syntax I know of that will achieve what you want to achieve. Replace the failing line with this

```
database.ref(`users/${uid}/movies/1234`).set(movie);
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Your answer worked and so did this: database.ref(`users/${uid}/movies`).child('12345').set(movie);